# How can I write code in the code-behind file for my ASP.NET 2.0 page that hides table rows without changing the IDs of the child elements?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I'm stumped by a seemingly simple problem. In my ASP.NET page, I have a table which has a few rows that need to be shown or hidden conditionally from the back end. Sounds simple, right?

What I tried is something like this in the front-end code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="demorow1">
       <p>This row always shows up!</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="conditionalrow" runat="server">
    <td id="formoptionsrow">
      <!-- This row contains a number of form elements that should only SOMETIMES be shown, as determined by the back-end code. -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in the code-behind file I just do this to hide the code:

```
conditionalrow.Style["display"] = "none";
```

This makes the row disappear as intended. I don't mind that it's just invisible, it won't hurt anything. However, this has the side-effect of making several HTML form elements inside of `conditionalrow` gain ASP.NET's convoluted IDs and NAMEs. This throws off a lot of Javascript functions related to the form that I don't have time to change or rework right now. I need to be able to hide the form (or remove it from the code entirely) from the code behind file, but without changing the IDs and NAMEs of child elements.

I know there's some kind of setting in the newer versions of ASP.NET that allows you to override ASP.NET's ID reassignment. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with ASP.NET 2.0 and don't have the option of using anything newer for this project. What do you recommend?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to do. You want to hide form-elements or forms in `conditionalrow` or do you want to remove it from HTML? Latter could be achieved easily by using the `Visible` property of conditionalrow, because it is already `runat=server`, it won't be rendered in HTML at all.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - I want to be able to toggle the visibility of the TR from the back end. Could just be invisible (in my example), or it could be removed from the HTML rendering entirely. Either way is fine. However, when the TR *is* visible, I want to child nodes of the TR to have the IDs and NAMEs I originally inputted into the code, without the changes that ASP.NET makes when an element is `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making the row a server side control, use a [code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) to give it an appropriate CSS class.

```
<tr class="<%:VisibilityClass%>">
```

Where, in your code behind you have a `VisibilityClass` string property that return the CSS class name:

```
public string VisibilityClass
{
  get 
  {
    if(shouldBeVisible)
      return "visible";

    return "hidden";
  }
}
```

You can also use functions if a property is not appropriate.

Comment: Awesome! So simple and yet I would never have thought of that at this rate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Never used code-blocks to set client-attributes, nice idea `+1`

Answer (score 0):

can you not do a conditionalrow.Visible = false;

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem that the child `<td id="formoptionsrow">` gets turned into `<td id="ctl00_MainContent_conditionalrow_formoptionsrow">` or something like that. The problem I need to solve is the changing IDs of the row's child elements.

Comment: @Joshua Carmody: Setting `Visible` to false at serverside means that ASP.NET won't render the HTML at all, hence `conditionalrow` and `formoptionsrow` won't even exist at clientside.

Comment: are you saying that even after you set the visible to false on the parent element, it still has the child elements in html? I thought setting the visible property to false will remove all of them.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, but I only want the rows to be hidden sometimes. So if I set `Visible` to true the child nodes will have the mangled IDs because their parent is `runat="server"`.